# Create view that can be used on all lists and subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, view

We have a custom view that we'd like to be able to use everywhere on our site including all the subsites. Is there a way to set it up once and have it deploy everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean custom list view?

I don't think it's possible to reuse a custom list view in all lists and sites.